# New warning when building android app with gradle

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

Yesterday it was fine, today it shows this warning when I clean or build the project:

> WARNING: Ignoring Android API artifact
>   com.google.android:android:2.1_r1 for appDebug WARNING: Ignoring Android
>   API artifact com.google.android:android:2.1_r1 for appRelease

I think it was caused by an update of the gradle plugin for android.

Anyone knows what it means ?

Comment: It is caused by the gradle plugin for sure - i've just updated it for one of my projects and it started throwing the same.. no idea so far what it is.

Comment: I have this warning 'Warning:Ignoring Android API artifact com.google.android:android:1.6_r2 for debug' since yesterday, when I update to Android Studio 2.2. But I have updated all libraries on project.

Comment: Are you using logback?

Comment: @DouglasMarques No I am not using logback

Comment: Me neither @DouglasMarques :-(

Comment: Issue reported https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=222538

Comment: is anyone got the solution to this raised question? Below mention answer not worked well for me.
Please reply if anyone got the solution..

Answer (score 17):

Usually, java libraries depends on `com.google.android:android` if this library will be used in Android project.

Then you can exclude this module from dependencies of target Android project. Like this:

```
compile ('some.library.that.depends.on.android') {
    exclude group: 'com.google.android'
}
```

Comment: Cool, I added the exclude group for logback and no warnings anymore

Comment: Exactly, in my case it was 'com.github.tony19:logback-android-classic:1.1.1-3' that was causing the problem.

Comment: @iDroidExplorer try to post your gradle used libraries

Comment: @Mohamed do you have any solution for this?

Comment: @senneco how to know that which library is causing this issue?

Comment: @iDroidExplorer you will know from the warning message and yes the solution is to exclude group from where you got the warning.

Comment: @senneco But how to identify, from where the warning comes.

Comment: I can not exclude this from all the library.

Answer (score -1):

I solved the problem by updating my version of gradle.

build.gradle (Project)

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:+'
```

Comment: What your Android Studio version?

Comment: 2.2, Filipe Henrique