# Warnings with Gradle about artifacts after update to Android Studio 2.2

Tags: android-studio, gradle, warnings

a few days ago I've updated to Android Studio 2.2. After this, I've had a couple of warnings in my project:

```
Warning:Ignoring Android API artifact com.google.android:android:1.6_r2 for debug
Warning:Ignoring Android API artifact com.google.android:android:1.6_r2 for release
```

Anyone knows the reason about it?

Comment: similar error was reported here https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=222538

Comment: duplicate:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37324917/new-warning-when-building-android-app-with-gradle

Comment: Is it the same error, @xsveda?

Comment: @GabrielMorenoIbarra: yep, I've encountered similar "WARNING: Ignoring Android API artifact com.google.android:android:2.2 for debug" after upgrade to AS 2.2 and Android plugin 2.2.0. The root cause is unknown for me but will be the same...

Comment: Aha, @xsveda. I've seen it before. But maybe you are right.

Comment: May be this helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39732424/1396039

Comment: Thank you, @senneco. But I don't known what library would have to add that :-(

Comment: @GabrielMorenoIbarra print all dependencies and then you can find, which depends on android ;) Have many ways to see all dependencies. Much popular way is some like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35235229/1396039

Answer (score 0):

At last, I find out the problem. It was caused by AndroidVideoCache library. To solve it, simply replace this (in my specific case):

```
compile 'com.danikula:videocache:2.6.3'
```

by

```
compile('com.danikula:videocache:2.6.3') {
    exclude group: 'com.google.android', module: 'android'
}
```