# Ignoring Android API artifact com.google.android:android:2.2.1 for debug/release

Tags: android, android-studio-2.2

```
Warning:Ignoring Android API artifact com.google.android:android:2.2.1 for debug
Warning:Ignoring Android API artifact com.google.android:android:2.2.1 for release
```

Android studio upgrade to 2.2, the compiler version will appear the following error, which is why? Do not understand, request settlement, thank you.

**Upgrade to the latest version of AndroidStudio no longer appear this problem, is the tool bug?**

Comment: Check out related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37324917/new-warning-when-building-android-app-with-gradle

Comment: Read it, but I didn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the latest version in your build.gradle?

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.1'
}
```

Comment: That does not seem to help in my case.

Comment: Has added a reference to gradle output, but it does not solve my problem